# Changing ArcGIS map service language?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps, internationalization, arcgis-online-webmap

I'm using [this](https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Reference/MapServer/0) ArcGIS map service as the basis for an application I'm developing.

However, this base map is in English, and for my application, it's necessary that the labels be displayed in Brazilian Portuguese.

Is it possible to change the language of this base map?

If this is not possible, is there an alternative to the ArcGIS map service where you can change the language?

Comment: That's not so much an "ArcGIS map" as an "ArcGIS Online map service".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change that basemap, but there are localized alternatives. See [this blog](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/announcements/whats-new-in-esri-vector-basemaps-february-2019/) for a list of localized basemaps.

You'll notice in the blog, [Brazilian Portuguese](https://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?id=da5696ea6c354222887fe5c8ddd87468#overview) is available, with the [Light Grey basemap](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=536f60c5c78d4c909d87246de27f5745). Note, these are VectorTile basemaps, not a "map service" like you reference. If you're working strictly in ArcGIS Online and webmaps there, it wont be a problem. If you're writing JavaScript to create a custom application, you'll need to ensure you use the right code to call VectorTiles.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the language, what you are seeing is essentially an image.
The answer is to find Portuguese basemaps that meet your need such as:

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9ed4b2a4d4dc4325bf5432d93957a37b

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=18b12639bc284be78d8d36a2ba48d1e9

or even better, compile your own.